# Populating Pandas/Python column based on another dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas, analysis

I've been a longtime lurker and I've managed to snag a new project involving some data munging. Specifically, I have around 5k master records to which I need to add a column with a specific value. Now that value lives in another dataframe/csv and I intend on matching the two based on a value within the master record. KEY DETAIL: This other list that I'm mating the master record against is only 60 possible values.

Kinda like if I wanted to insert the state to an address file if all I had was the city and a list of cities within states.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Comment: I was going to try that; but it seems like merge combines the two DFs together....I instead need the rows in master to get the data in XX column updated based upon the values in another dataframe of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect the two tables on a column, see [merging dataframes in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Since you mentioned there is a small number of values to match on, you could try a map.

```
d = {'Washington':'Olympia', 'California':'Sacramento'}
df['capital'] = df.state.map(d)
```